# How do I display current cell address of an org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, mode-line

I am trying to write some formulas in my tables and having a bit of a hard time figuring out the current cell's address (`@row:$col`).

It would be awesome if I could display the cell location in the mode-line but I am okay with some function that prints out the locations in `*messages*`.

Comment: You can have org show row and column numbers by org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays, bound to C-c } by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coordinates can be displayed with <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> - `org-table-toggle-coordinate-overlays`. It shows the coordinates within the table:

```
| a | b | c |
|---+---+---|
|foo|bar|baz|
|baz|bar|foo|
|bar|baz|foo|
```

will display as:

```
    1| a   | b   | c   |                                                                                                                       
 I*1 |$1---+$2---+$3---|                                                                                                                       
    2| foo | bar | baz |                                                                                                                       
    3| baz | bar | foo |                                                                                                                       
    4| bar | baz | foo |
```

From [worg](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-and-debugging-formulas.html):

Toggle the display of row and column numbers for a table, using overlays. These are updated each time the table is aligned; you can force it with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.